# Retrieving nation and street address with google maps api v3 reverse geocoding

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I need to retrieve the: street address, nation and maybe also region starting from an array of coordinates.

**I'm using this function:**

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$long&sensor=false";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$curlData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$data = json_decode($curlData);

$address = $data->results[0]->address_components[1]->long_name.', '.$data->results[0]->address_components[0]->long_name;
$country = $data->results[0]->address_components[5]->long_name;
$nation = $data->results[0]->address_components[6]->long_name;
```

This script itself is working and I get back results, but I've noticed that values are not  in the same place every time, (I think depending by the available result) so I got wrong values. Ho can I fix that?

**Here are two examples of my output, for one location:**

http://urbanfiles.linkmesrl.com/files/uploads/test_address_1.php

http://urbanfiles.linkmesrl.com/files/uploads/test_address_2.php

Any suggestion to get the right value for my results?

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the address components and decide the type from the array "types" field.

```
<?php
foreach($data->results[0]->address_components as $address_component){
    if(in_array('country', $address_component->types)){
        $country = $address_component->long_name;
        continue;
    } elseif(in_array('route', $address_component->types)) {
        $address = $address_component->long_name;
        continue;
    }
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Worked Like a charm!
Just added 's' after result and type
Thank You very much!